# Yield rates for priming sugar calculations

Tags: priming, priming-sugar, calculations

I am trying to figure out how Priming Sugar calculators work under the hood and just gave [this illuminating article](https://homebrewacademy.com/priming-sugar-calculator/) a read.

Most of it makes sense, however the author talks about each different priming sugar having a different "yield rate" and I am wondering if that metric is the same as the **Dry Yields** I see for each ingredient on [BeerSmith](http://beersmith.com/grain-list/).

For instance, Honey is [listed on BeerSmith](http://www.beersmith.com/Grains/Grains/grain_43.htm) as having a Dry Yield of 75%. Does that mean, that if I calculate I need 4oz of corn sugar (which is 42 PPG @ 100% yield), I would need 5.894oz of Honey (168/38/0.75)?

If not, then what is this "yield rate" and where can I find it for...*every* priming sugar (!!!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is a bit misleading as normally Dry Yield means that a solution is "dried" and subsequently as much sugar is extracted. Honey has about ~95% fermentables but also contains about 15~18% moisture. So if the Dry Yield is indicated as 75% it means that you are looking at the "raw ingredient" which also contains the moisture. While misleading this does make it easier for homebrewers as it makes the overall calculation easier.

The dry yield is used to indicate the "efficiency" of extraction under ideal conditions (e.g. lab) conditions as compared to a 100% extraction of sucrose. Note that for grains this may vary between a homebrewer and a malthouse, because sugar extraction is more complex than just ... using sugar. But for honey/sugar there probably is not much difference.

With regard to your formula, that's exactly correct. 1.168 would be your yield for solving 4 lb of corn sugar in 1 gallon of water. To get to 1.168 with raw honey (yielding 38 PPG with 75% efficiency) you would need 5.894 oz honey.